My pump keeps losing prime and I don't know why
My zoeller pump is losing prime in the pump. The lines are staying full of water and it's not visibly leaking anywhere. I only have to add about a cup of water each time it loses prime to fill it back up. it's been running for around 10 to 15 minutes before losing prime. the pump is a zoeller 1hp deep well pump

Are you sure it's not running dry with having been running for 10-15 min when it looses prime?
